# Script To Look Up Nameservers On Multiple Domains

Tags: bash, sed, whois, dig

I am working on migrating a customer's WHM / cPanel account to a new server, however he has many, many sites hosted on the server that I need to retrieve their nameservers.

I'd like to create a bash script that parses a file (with each domain on a separate line), performs a `dig` and `whois`, finds the nameserver and IP, and then outputs the domain and its nameserver to another file.

I'm not very good with bash, but I have found and edited this script - but it doesn't seem to want to work at all. If anyone has any insight, that would be great. Thanks!

```
#!/bin/bash
# dig $line +short >> ip address 
# whois $line >> Lists full details including the name servers 
# whois $line | grep "Name Server" | cut -d ":" -f 2 | sed 's/ //' | 
# sed -e :a -e '$!N;s/ \n/,/;ta'`  
while read inputfile 
do 
echo $domain  
ipaddress=`dig $domain +short` 
nameserver=`whois $domain | grep "Name Server" | cut -d ":" -f 2 |    
sed 's/ //' | sed -e :a -e '$!N;s/ \n/,/;ta'` 
echo -e "$domain,$ipaddress,$nameserver" >> outputfile
done
```

Comment: You aren't giving that first `sed` command any input data to work on (though that looks like it was meant to be part of the comment actually). Likewise you aren't giving the `read` command in the `while` loop any data to read from (usually redirected from a file or similar on the `done` line via `<input_file` or `< <(process that generates data)`.

Comment: Yes you are indeed correct, that first `sed` was intended to be a comment. Ugh, I need to work on my bash.

Comment: Is `inputfile` there supposed to be the file that contains the domains? Because the arguments to `read` are the variables to assign the read data to not the file/etc. to read the data from. `read` reads from standard input by default (so `read line <inputfile` will read the first line of `inputfile` into the `line` variable). You probably want `while IFS= read -r line` and `done <inputfile` there. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 for more.

Comment: Well that pretty much got me to where I needed. Much appreciated Etan! Only problem now is that some of these domains are `.br` and the whois doesn't return nameservers, ugh. Nothing you can help me with though hah. Again, thank you!

EDIT: Woah what am I thinking. I forgot about `dig ns`. Man is it Friday yet? :P

Comment: You should not use whois to get a working domain name nameservers. list Just use the DNS.

Answer (score 1):

This will output all possible A and NS records of domains in given file:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read domain 
do 

for a in `dig $domain a +short`
do
    ipaddress="$ipaddress$a,"
done

for ns in `dig $domain ns +short`
do
    nameserver="$nameserver$ns,"
done 
echo "$domain,$ipaddress,$nameserver"
done
```

usage

Suppose script is named as resolver and the file is input. Do

```
cat input | ./resolver
```

(Some domains have more than one ip addresses and name servers)

Comment: @EtanReisner Its all about the use case! Here, using for loop is ok for dig short output

Comment: You may know that but the OP may not. And reading lines with `for` is an anti-pattern and just shouldn't be used as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: OK then, I'll change it soon ;)